# UIImage Resizing Works, but Reverts to Original Size When Converted to Data for Upload

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm encountering a peculiar issue in my iOS app related to image resizing and uploading. I have implemented a method to resize images to fit within a specific size range (minimum size: 320px, maximum size: 1536px) before uploading them to a server. The resizing seems to work perfectly, as verified by inspecting the UIImage directly after resizing. However, the moment I convert the resized image to data (JPEG format) in preparation for the upload, it seems to revert to its original size or does not maintain the resized dimensions.

Here's the resizing method I'm using:

```swift
func resizedImage(minimumSize: CGFloat, maximumSize: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let originalWidth = size.width
    let originalHeight = size.height

    var scaleFactor: CGFloat
    var newWidth: CGFloat
    var newHeight: CGFloat

    if originalWidth < minimumSize || originalHeight < minimumSize {
        scaleFactor = max(minimumSize / originalWidth, minimumSize / originalHeight)
    } else if originalWidth > maximumSize || originalHeight > maximumSize {
        scaleFactor = min(maximumSize / originalWidth, maximumSize / originalHeight)
    } else {
        scaleFactor = 1.0
    }

    newWidth = originalWidth * scaleFactor
    newHeight = originalHeight * scaleFactor

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight), false, 0)
    draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return resizedImage
}
```

After resizing, when I attempt to convert the resized UIImage into data like so:

```swift
if let resizedImage = resizedImage(minimumSize: 320, maximumSize: 1536) {
    let imageData = resizedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
    // Proceed to upload imageData
}
```

Despite the resizing, the `imageData` seems to reflect the original image size rather than the resized one. This issue occurs before the upload, during the preparation of the image data for the request body. The goal is to ensure that the image uploaded to the server adheres to the specified size limits. Is there something I'm overlooking in the resizing or data conversion process that could cause the image to revert to its original dimensions?

Any advice or insights on how to ensure the resized image maintains its dimensions when converted to data for upload would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, if your goal is to make smaller assets, a JPEG with compression quality of 1 will create a relatively large asset for the respective dimensions. Usually a compression quality of 0.7-0.8 yields a decent image with (admittedly) lossy compression. If you want lossless compression, PNG format is an alternative, smaller than JPEG with compression quality of 1.0, but not generally as small as JPEG with compression quality of 0.7-0.8. (Also, FWIW, PNG will preserve transparency information, if any.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623912-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwitho) with that last parameter using a scale of `0` means that it will use the scale of the device. E.g., if rendering an image into a size of 100×100 with a scale of `0` on a device featuring a Retina 3× screen, the resulting `UIImage` will have a [`size`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624105-size) with “logical dimensions” of 100×100pt, but its [`scale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624110-scale) will be is `3`: That means that the resulting JPEG will be 300×300px.

So, check not only the `size` of the resulting image, but its `scale`, too. In short, consider using a scale of `1`, not `0`, if you want the resulting image to be to match your intended min/max dimension, in pixels, specified in the parameters to your function.

---

FWIW, `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` is now deprecated and has been replaced with [`UIGraphicsImageRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer). So, if you want to use a scale of `1`, perhaps:

```swift
extension UIImage {
    func resizedImage(minimumSize: CGFloat, maximumSize: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let originalWidth = size.width
        let originalHeight = size.height
        
        let resizeFactor: CGFloat = if originalWidth < minimumSize || originalHeight < minimumSize {
            max(minimumSize / originalWidth, minimumSize / originalHeight)
        } else if originalWidth > maximumSize || originalHeight > maximumSize {
            min(maximumSize / originalWidth, maximumSize / originalHeight)
        } else {
            1
        }
        
        let width = originalWidth * resizeFactor
        let height = originalHeight * resizeFactor
        
        let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = 1
        
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds, format: format).image { _ in
            draw(in: bounds)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, a `scale` of `0` has utility. E.g., if you have an image view which is 100×100, you may *want* an image size of 300×300px (or 100×100pt with a scale of `3`) or else it might look pixelated on modern, high-resolution devices. Above, I have tried to answer the question of why the JPG dimensions were higher than you expected, but when deciding the desired max dimensions in px, make sure you consider not only the size of the control you will be showing the image, but also whether it will be shown on high resolution devices or not.

Comment: No amount of thanks could be enough. You've saved my week; thank you so much.